# Convert 2D array in Java to Image

Tags: java, image, image-processing

I need to convert a 2D array of pixel intensity data of a grayscale image back to an image. I tried this:

```
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(
    regen.length, regen[0].length, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);  
for(int x = 0; x < regen.length; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y<regen[x].length; y++){
        img.setRGB(x, y, (int)Math.round(regen[x][y]));
    }
}
File imageFile = new File("D:\\img\\conv.bmp");
ImageIO.write(img, "bmp", imageFile);
```

where "regen" is a 2D double array. I am getting an output which is similar but not exact. There are few pixels that are totally opposite to what it must be (I get black color for a pixel which has a value of 255). Few gray shades are also taken as white. Can you tell me what is the mistake that I am doing?

Comment: A shot in the dark: possible rounding issue from double to int?

Comment: No that is not the problem i guess..most pixels are already an integer. they are just in a double array. also for the remaining few, the pixel vales are too close to an int.. for eg: i have 254.9999999999 for 255 so it must round off definitely to 255.

Answer (score 2):

Try some code like this:

```
public void writeImage(int Name) {
    String path = "res/world/PNGLevel_" + Name + ".png";
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(color.length, color[0].length, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    for (int x = 0; x < 200; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 200; y++) {
            image.setRGB(x, y, color[x][y]);
        }
    }

    File ImageFile = new File(path);
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", ImageFile);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY` is unsigned and non-indexed. Moreover,

> When data with non-opaque alpha is stored in an image of this type, the color data must be adjusted to a non-premultiplied form and the alpha discarded, as described in the `AlphaComposite` documentation.

At a minimum you need to preclude sign extension and mask off all but the lowest eight bits of the third parameter to `setRGB()`. Sample data that reproduces the problem would be dispositive.

Comment: i don't think alpha component may be the issue. because even if i have all the values as 255.0 in the double array, i am still getting an image with black pixels.

Comment: You might verify the image dimensions and edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem.